# How to programmatically obtain another device ip on an IOS ad hoc network?

Tags: ios, networking, bonjour

I have a DLSR Canon camera connected directly via wiFi ("ad hoc" network) to an iOS device running iOS 10.

How do I programmatically determine the address of the camera?  I want to send PTP ("Picture Transfer Protocol") messages to the device and receive the camera data on the iOS device.

I know I'm connected as WiFi network menu on the iOS device Network menu indicates I'm connected.

I can determine the iOS device IP address from within the app, but not the "other end point" of the network.  (BTW, I'm using Objective-C.)

Is there a method in Bonjour I could use?  Or something in Multipeer Connectivity?  I don't know what the Bonjour service name, hostname or IP address would be for the camera.    I know this is possible as Canon provides an app that does this very thing.

Comment: It is likely that Canon has a protocol the sends via broadcast or multicast. It may share this with you if you ask, or it may consider it proprietary.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  I've got Canon's SDK and their documentation is terrible.  But doesn't iOS have a mechanism to determine the IP address of any device on an Ad Hoc (or "direct") WiFi network?  I guess I could send a programmatic ping to all the link local address, but that seems like brute force.

Comment: Well, there is a difference between finding all the devices connected to a network (network protocols don't actually support this, and it is possible to prevent it in a few ways) and finding a specific device on a network. Many device manufacturers have a discovery protocol for their devices.